# An error in loading deep learning model via pickle

Tags: python, keras, pickle

I made a deep learning model using Keras and stored it in a folder named `model.pkl` and for loading the model for deployment I used the code i.e.

```
import pickle
model = pickle.load(open('/home/samar/Desktop/ckd/model.pkl', 'rb'))
prediction = model.predict(data)
```

But it returned me as

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/samar/Desktop/ckd/model.pkl'
```

Though the folder is present there still it's giving the error.

I saved the model via `model.save('model.pkl')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `model.save()` method doesn't actually pickle it, you would want to use the built-in model loader from keras to load your model, like this:

```
model = keras.models.load_model('/home/samar/Desktop/ckd/model.pkl')
prediction = model.predict(data)
```